# Show that the change of variables transforms a linear system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, coordinate-systems

Show that the change of variables $x=2u+v$, $y=3u+v$ transforms the linear system
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
x'(t) &= \phantom{3}x-2y \\ 
y'(t) &= 3x-4y
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
into
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
u'(t) & = -2u \\
v'(t) &= -v
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

Verify that the $u$-axis maps to the line $y=\frac{3}{2}x$ and the $v$-axis maps to the line $y=x$.

I thought for this I would just have to plug the substitutions into $x'(t)$ and $y'(t)$ but when doing this I receive
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
u'(t) &= 2u+v-2(3u+v)    \hskip-15pt&= -4u-v \\
v'(t) &= 3(2u+v)-4(3u+v) \hskip-15pt&= -6u-v
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems there is an error in the question.  What you did is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, but what you've shown is that
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
x' &= -4u-v \\
y' &= -6u-v
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
By subbing in expressions in $u$ and $v$ for $x$ and $y$, you can convert the right sides of these equations to the new variables. But you also need to convert the left sides (the derivatives), and for that you need to reverse that change of variables.

---

Details: using your favorite technique from linear algebra, you can find
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
x &= 2u + v \\
y &= 3u + v
\end{aligned}
\right.
\qquad\Longleftrightarrow\qquad
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
u &= -x + \phantom{2}y \\
v &= \hskip2.5pt 3x - 2y
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

Thus,
\begin{align}
u' &= (-x + y)' \\
&= -x' + y' \\
&= -(x-2y) + (3x-4y) \\
&= 2x - 2y \\
&= 2(2u+v) - 2(3u+v) \\
&= -2u
\end{align}

I leave the analogous calculation that $v' = -v$ up to you.

---

If you squint really hard, you can see that what you are doing is diagonalizing a square matrix by converting to basis of eigenvalues:
$P^{-1}AP = D$, i.e.
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 1 \\ 3 & -2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -2 \\ 3 & -4
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 \\ 3 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & 0 \\ 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: How do I verify that the $u$-axis maps to $y=\frac{3}{2}x$ and the $v$-axis maps to $y=x$? Since I receive that $u=-x+y$ and $v=3x-2y$ wouldn't the opposite be true?

Comment: The $u$-axis is defined by the equation $v=0$, which is equivalent to $y=\frac32 x$. Analogously, the $v$-axis is defined by the equation $u=0$, which is equivalent to $y=x$.